# ¿Como capturar pantalla en video con angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Debo crear un función que capture en video la pantalla de la aplicación, investigue y logre encontrar este plugin:

https://github.com/sebible/cordova-videosnapshot

Si alguien lo a utilizado podría compartir la manera de instalarlo o si saben de otro plugin que cumpla esta función o si se debe programar dicho plugin para cumplir la tarea.